# How to create a new csv file with separate columns in a shorter way

Tags: python-3.x, function, csv

I created a function that does a few calculations, and managed to get the right data in the right way in the csv file. However, my code is really long and reading through other threads on this topic I did not find an easy way to shorten it. My code is the following:

```
def modelc(x,Mblood,Mliver,dt):
createFile = open('Time.csv', 'w')
createFile.write('t'+'\n')
createFile.close()

createFile = open('Blood.csv', 'w')
createFile.write('Mblood'+'\n')
createFile.close()

createFile = open('Liver.csv', 'w')
createFile.write('Mliver'+'\n')
createFile.close()

while x<24:
    Mblood = Mblood-Mblood*0.5*dt
    Mliver = Mliver+Mblood*0.5*dt
    x+=dt

    appendFile = open('Time.csv','a')
    appendFile.write('%f'%x+'\n')
    appendFile.close()

    appendFile = open('Blood.csv','a')
    appendFile.write('%f'%Mblood+'\n')
    appendFile.close()

    appendFile = open('Liver.csv','a')
    appendFile.write('%f'%Mliver+'\n')
    appendFile.close()

    csv_input = pandas.read_csv('Time.csv')
    csv_blood = pandas.read_csv('Blood.csv')
    csv_liver = pandas.read_csv('Liver.csv')
    csv_input['MassBlood'] = csv_blood['Mblood']
    csv_input['MassLiver'] = csv_liver['Mliver']
    csv_input.to_csv('Modeloutput.csv', index=False)

modelc(0,20,0,0.001)
```

The CSV file then looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQiFb.png)

Does anyone have a simple way of achieving the same result with a shorter code?

Comment: You use already pandas. You may directly append the values inside a pandas dataframe and save that as you do in last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening and closing takes a long time since it uses the HD memory. Instead leave the file opened (in secondary memory), do all the operations and close and save in the very end.

```
   def modelc(x,Mblood,Mliver,dt):
       createFile = open('Liver.csv', 'wt')
       createFile.write("t,MassBlood,MassLiver")
       for i in range(24):
          Mblood = Mblood-Mblood*0.5*dt
          Mliver = Mliver+Mblood*0.5*dt
          x+=dt
          createFile.write(str(x)+","+str(Mblood)+","+str(Mliver))
    createFile.close()
```